# Extract only numbers with 8 digits and does not followed by contain characters (. , @)

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I am using a function to extract numbers from string with conditions that number with **8 digits** and does not contain characters (**. , @**).
It works with 8 digits , but if the number is followed by characters (**. , @**) ,it also extract that number and that not required.
This my string `11111111  12345678.1 11111112 11111113` and the expected output is **11111111 11111112 11111113** without 12345678.1.
I tried to use negative Lookahead `\d{8}(?!.,@)` but it is useless.
Thanks all for your help.

```
Function Find8Numbers(st As String) As Variant
    Dim regex As New RegExp
     Dim matches As MatchCollection, mch As match
 
     regex.Pattern = "\d{8}"      'Look for variable length numbers only
     regex.IgnoreCase = True
     regex.Global = True
     regex.MultiLine = True
 
    If (regex.Test(st) = True) Then
      Set matches = regex.Execute(st)   'Execute search
        For Each mch In matches
              Find8Numbers = LTrim(Find8Numbers) & " " & mch.value
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I would just use find() and not vba - lots of examples exist on here.

Comment: @Solar Mike ,that function is just a piece on my vba code

Comment: When working with regex it always pays to test your regex expression against a sample of text outside of the VBA environment.  There are many sites on the internet that can do this test, e.g. https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html

Comment: @freeflow ,thanks and that is a great info

Comment: Actually, a regex tester is built into the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In line with your question and current attempt, you could indeed use regex:

```
Function Find8Numbers(st As String) As String

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Pattern = "(?:^|\s)(\d{8})(?![.,@\d])"
    .Global = True
    If .Test(st) Then
        Set Matches = .Execute(st)
        For Each mch In Matches
            Find8Numbers = LTrim(Find8Numbers & " " & mch.submatches(0))
        Next
    End If
End With

End Function
```

Invoke through:

```
Sub Test()

Dim s As String: s = "11111111  12345678.1 11111112 11111113"
Debug.Print Find8Numbers(s)

End Sub
```

Prints:

```
11111111 11111112 11111113
```

---

Pattern used:

```
(?:^|\s)(\d{8})(?![.,@\d])
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kysKwv/1)

- `(?:^|\s)` - No lookbehind in VBA thus used a non-capture group to match start-line anchor *or* whitespace;
- `(\d{8})` - Exactly 8 digits in capture group;
- `(?![.,@\d])` - Negative lookahead to assert position isn't followed by any of given characters *including* digits.

Comment: Woww, this is very well explained and very informative answer, thanks for sharing, cheers. So vb script supports PCRE regex OR it follows POSIX one, just asking for info.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks! Also, VBScript follows Perl-style regular expressions like JavaScript but lacks a bunch of features. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60192760/9758194).

Comment: It works perfectly .
I see also you changed `mch.value` with **mch.SubMatches(0)** , Please what is the difference ?

Comment: @Leedo, it's a reference to the 1st capture group. In the pattern I wanted to exclude possible leading whitespace from the match since `Trim()` does not replace extra spaces inside string; I wanted to prevent using `Application.Trim()` thus opted for a capture group.

Comment: @Leedo, you could revert back to work without a capture group, but `\s` is shorthand for any type of whitespace character. Meaning; you could have newline, tabs etc. before numbers and you want to return a space delimited string, hence my choice for a capture group.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you need Regex for what is a reasonably simple pattern. You could just go with a VBA solution:

```
Public Function Find8Numbers(str As String) As String
    Dim c As String, c1 As String
    Dim i As Long, numStart As Long
    Dim isNumSeq As Boolean
    Dim result As String
    
    If Len(str) < 8 Then Exit Function
    
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        c = Mid(str, i, 1)
        If i = Len(str) Then
            c1 = ""
        Else
            c1 = Mid(str, i + 1, 1)
        End If
        If c >= "0" And c <= "9" Then
            If isNumSeq Then
                If i - numStart + 1 = 8 Then
                    If c1 <> "." And c1 <> "," And c1 <> "@" Then
                        If result <> "" Then result = result & " "
                        result = result & Mid(str, numStart, 8)
                        isNumSeq = False
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                If i > Len(str) - 8 + 1 Then Exit For
                isNumSeq = True
                numStart = i
            End If
        Else
            isNumSeq = False
        End If
    Next
    Find8Numbers = result
End Function
```